# How to Verify JAVA_HOME path

Tags: bash, java, environment-variables, jre

I installed java in opt/jdk1.7.75 having following directories-->

```
bin
db
include
jre
lib
man
COPYRIGHT
LICENSE
README.html
relase
```

& other files
I set JAVA_HOME path in `.bashrc` file as follow:

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.75
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

On running `echo $JAVA_HOME` path it is pointing as follow:

`/opt/jdk1.7.75`

My question is How to verify if the path is correct or incorrect? As most post says run echo command, echo simply gives the path what u have set,it does not tell you if it is correct or incorrect.

Can anybody explain How to VERIFY path is correct or incorrect

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: You want `JAVA_HOME` to override other things in `PATH`, so it should come first: `export PATH="$JAVA_HOME:$PATH"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$JAVAHOME` is pointing to the correct location. But the path should have `$JAVAHOME/bin` directory and not `$JAVAHOME` itself.

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk1.7.75"
export JAVA_HOME
PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

---

You should consider using the Oracle Java PPA instead. It usually does more than what a manual installation would do. You don't have to worry about setting up the environment variables either. That's what most people use.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

---

Try running `java -version` and `javac -version` to verify that the path is set.

Comment: thanks for ur ans, but my question was how to verify? is there any command or someway, which tells JAVA_HOME path is incorrect?

Comment: Just try running `java -version` and `javac`.

Comment: java -version gaves the same output as it was giving before setting JAVA_HOME path, same goes for javac

Comment: @NarendraJaggi See the updated answer.

Comment: Put `$JAVA_HOME/bin` before the existing entries in `PATH`: `export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`". Otherwise `/usr/bin/java` will override `$HAVA_HOME/bin/java`.

Comment: I removed the JAVA_HOME path<br/>Now echo $JAVA_HOME is giving empty string in result. And the commands java -version giving java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
 AND  javac  -version giving javac 1.7.0_75.    SO These commands are working even without giving JAVA_HOME. Can u please explain that

Comment: Enter `echo $PATH`. What's the output?

Comment: gives blank line on enter press,No error nothing, simply blank line

Comment: Ohh, that can't be. Are you typing the right command?

Comment: Oh i ws saying about the echo $JAVA_HOME, For echo $PATH result is /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: I think you're running `java -version` while you're in the `/opt/jdk1.7.75` folder. Try `cd` into a different folder and then enter `java -version`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23363/discussion-between-narendra-jaggi-and-reversiblean).

Comment: I m in root directory /

Comment: @muru echo $PATH is giving this result -->
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/jdk1.7.75
I don't think it overrides anything

Answer (score 0):

If you have `update-java-alternatives` installed, just type

```
$>update-java-alternatives -l
```

From the manual `man update-java-alternatives`

> DESCRIPTION
>          update-java-alternatives  updates all alternatives belonging to one runtime or development kit for the Java language.  A package does
>   provide these information of it's alter‐
>          natives in /usr/lib/jvm/..jinfo.
>
> OPTIONS
>          -l|--list []
>                 List all installed packages (or just ) providing information to set a bunch of java alternatives. Verbose output shows
>   each alternative provided  by  the  pack‐
>                 ages.

If you don't have it installed, simply run

```
$>ls -l /usr/bin/java
```

It should return a pointer to the java bin file, something like

```
$>ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 ott 16  2013 /usr/bin/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

JAVA_HOME is the part previous to jre, so in my case `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to run java commands like

```
java --version
```

from the terminal, the `PATH` is correct and in turn, the `JAVA_HOME` variable is correct.

Comment: without PATH these command will not run?

Comment: yes, they wont.  If you want to run an executable `file`  saved in `/path/to/executable/`, you have to give `/path/to/executable/file` to run it if it is not saved in `PATH` or any other environment variable. The very fact that you are able to run `java --version` proves that your path is right.

Comment: i didn't set, but its wrkng, may b i use java alternative command so these things r nt reqrd, as i didn't set any path @ first point

Comment: run `env` | `grep java` . If there is a path to your java location. It is set.