# Installation of OpenModelica

Tags: software-installation, environment-variables

I wished to install OpenModelica on my deb-based system, ubuntu 18.04.
For this purpose, I used the following commands:

```
echo "deb http://build.openmodelica.org/apt bionic stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openmodelica.list 
echo "deb-src http://build.openmodelica.org/apt bionic stable" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openmodelica.list
wget -q http://build.openmodelica.org/apt/openmodelica.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openmodelica
```

The second half of the result of last command was,

```
0 upgraded, 78 newly installed, 0 to remove and 149 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 28.2 MB/123 MB of archives.
After this operation, 567 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 llvm-6.0 amd64 1:6.0-1ubuntu2 [4,838 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 llvm-6.0-dev amd64 1:6.0-1ubuntu2 [23.0 MB]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 qt-at-spi amd64 0.4.0-8 [58.6 kB]
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 xsltproc amd64 1.1.29-5ubuntu0.2 [14.0 kB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libomp5 amd64 5.0.1-1 [234 kB]
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libomp-dev amd64 5.0.1-1 [5,088 B]
Fetched 25.1 MB in 6min 37s (63.2 kB/s)                                        
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Setting up install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 3: /etc/environment: JAVA_HOME: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please put your efforts to fix this error.

Reference: [Download Linux - OpenModelica](https://openmodelica.org/index.php/download/download-linux)

Comment: There is a space missing after `gedit`. However, the commands you mentioned don't appear in the linked reference. There are one-liners you can simply copy paste to a terminal instead of manually editing `sources.list`.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't follow the procedure explained in your link? Were you trying to perform a simplified procedure? (that is indeed an appreciable thing if you know what you are doing or you are trying also to learn).

Answer (score 0):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** (valid for this revision of the question https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1248743/1)

Your commands are wrong:

- your `echo` does not redirect the string to any file
- your `gedit` command is wrong (there's an unneded `/` between the command and the parameter)
- moreover it is trying to open the wrong file (typically you don't need to edit manually edit the sources.list file).

In https://openmodelica.org/download/download-linux I've seen that there is the correct installation sequence, you must only choose if you want to install the stable, nightly or release version.

**ADDENDUM:**
Even if you should simply copy/paste the instructions from the link that you added by yourself, I will rewrite them so that I can explain to you the meaning.
First of all, execute the following commands:

```
echo "deb http://build.openmodelica.org/apt bionic stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openmodelica.list
echo "deb-src http://build.openmodelica.org/apt bionic stable" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openmodelica.list
```

With the first command, you are copying the string inside the double quote to the file `openmodelica.list`. If the file exists, the string will overwrite its full content, otherwise the file is created and filled with the string.
This works because the `|` symbol immediately before the `sudo tee` part ***is not a separator*** but represents the "pipeline" command: you are using the output of the `echo` command as the input for the `tee` command (where `tee` is a command that writes in a file).

With the second command you are doing a similar things but with a difference: `tee` uses the parameter `-a`, that means: append the string to the content that is already present in the file.
At the end of the two command, if you open the `openmodelica.list` file, you will find that its content is:

```
deb http://build.openmodelica.org/apt bionic stable
deb-src http://build.openmodelica.org/apt bionic stable
```

If yes, you can go on.
After this, execute the following sequence of commands:

```
wget -q http://build.openmodelica.org/apt/openmodelica.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openmodelica
```

**ADDENDUM 2:** This application requires Java. Install it by running

`sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre`

Then retry the installation (restarting from the `sudo apt update` command), now it should work.

If problems persist, we need to check if `/etc/environment` files need to be modified. You should not need this, because after `java` installation the `java` executable has been added in one of the directory in `PATH` variable, so it should be globally visible.

In a terminal, run `sudo -H gedit /etc/environment`
If there in no JAVE_HOME line, don't delete any line, simply add at the end:
`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/"`

Then, retry the installation.

Comment: After following the exact installation sequence, ` echo "$deb http://build.openmodelica.org/apt `lsb_release -cs` stable" ` , I got this: `http://build.openmodelica.org/apt bionic stable ` . Nextly when entered this in the terminal `sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openmodelica.list`, just gave no result after putting up my system's password. Please explain why is this so?

Comment: It's because you are not following the exact instructions. Before the "sudo tee" part there is a | symbol that is fundamental: it means: the outpout of echi command must be the input of tee command, so that the string will be copied inside the .list file

Comment: I've modified my answer with some explanations.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating the installation sequence of the OpenModelica. This would have worked well, but my JAVA_HOME variable is not set up right showing out an error while processing. I have mentioned the error in detail in my edited question. Please suggest the way to fix it up.

Comment: which is the output of the command: "java -version"  in your terminal? (without double quote)

Comment: The output is: Command 'java' not found

Comment: Added other details. Some of the things I've written are easily found in this site at the links https://askubuntu.com/questions/617204/how-to-verify-java-home-path or https://askubuntu.com/questions/984763/usr-sbin-update-info-dir-1-etc-environment-java-home-not-found . Please, try to find a solution by yourself before asking.